# Filter multiple line text using content query webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-query-web-part

Is there any way we can filter content query webpart using multiple line text with contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to use multiple lines of text column with contains in the content query web part.